# Setting up a subdomain SSL with custom port

Tags: subdomain

I'm setting up a subdomain on a dedicated server that I'm going to use for SVN services.  The SVN server is up and running I just need to setup the subdomain.  The https has been switched to a custom port because there's a confliction with a port forward pointing to another server.

Should I do this through GoDaddy or Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running SSL on a port other than 443, you'll need to configure the web server to respond to requests on your custom port (that would be Apache in this case).  Anything that links to this URL will also need to include the custom port number in the link (ex: `https://host.example.com:port/`) in order to work properly.

Comment: No problem, GoDaddy issues the cert, but the certificate itself doesn't know or care what port the connection is running on.